# Randomly Rounding

Tags: code-golf, math, integer, random

Input a decimal number and round it to an integer, randomly rounding up or down with a probability based on its fractional part, so the expected value  of the output equals to the input value.

If input \$x\$ is an integer, the program should output it as is. If \$x\$ is not an integer, the program has a \$x-\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor\$ probability to output \$\left\lceil x \right\rceil\$, and a \$\lceil x\rceil-x\$ probability to output \$\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor\$.

In the above formula, \$\left\lfloor i\right\rfloor\$ means rounding \$i\$ down to the nearest integer; \$\left\lceil i\right\rceil\$ means rounding \$i\$ up to the nearest integer.

### Examples

- For input 2.4, it has 60% probability to output 2, and 40% probability to output 3.
- For input 3.9, it has 10% probability to output 3, and 90% probability to output 4.
- For input 0.5, it has 50% probability to output 0, and 50% probability to output 1.
- For input -5.25, it has 75% probability to output -5, and 25% probability to output -6.
- For input 8, it has 100% probability to output 8, and 0% probability to output 7 or 9.

### Rules

- To make the challenge easier, reasonable errors in probability are allowed.

  - For any input \$-100<x<100\$, the probability error should be less than \$0.01\%\$.
- You may assume your language's built-in random number generator is perfectly balanced.
- You may assume the input / output value fits your languages decimal number types, as long as [this does not trivialize the challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8245/44718).
- As usual, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). So shortest code wins.

Comment: What range of `x` should the program possibly handle?

Comment: @xiver77 Any reasonable range that at least support -100 ~ +100 with 4 decimal places (so it meets the requirement of probability error). Typically 32 bit IEEE 754 `float` type in most languages should be enough.

Comment: Note: This question is about code-golf. Never use any code on this page in any rational works. For example, `floor(input + randomFloat0To1())` could have a small probability output 9 for input 8 due to floating point errors. This is allowed in this question. But you would not want this happen in your real word codes.

Answer (score 13):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 6 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
⌊?⍤≡+⊢
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=e9TTZf@od8mjzoXaj7oWAQA&f=e9Q7VyGoNE8hNTE5QyE5sThVwU@hJDM3tVghMS9FoTgjv1yhJCNVITm/NK9EIT8Noq4otbg0p4TLT@FR2wQFQwMg4ApJLS4Bc6urH/XuUtB41LnoUe9WzdpHPTvSDq3we9S7BcithSgz0jPhUleHsI31LOFsAz1TOPvQelM9IwTXAgA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

Add a random number in \$(0,1)\$ and floor.

Answer (score 10):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 20 bytes

```
\(n)(n+runif(1))%/%1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ddHBasMgGMBxdt1TfFACShMb09gkY3uTXcw2WyGoJHros_SSQvsGe5Cd-zSLCCM7fB704N-fiJfrON8UvBb34FXRfr8TQ4nZjsFoRTil2S7jaevx9HOEN1DBfHhtzdKBG61jXvbDF0nzJJ0bzoS_8DKO_C_WVC0HlvF8JBWr6SYH7eEkJziUWXR62etB-zN4CzZ4FzxUOUjzCTUa7Nmi7Vm30jgeJ61DgzpqJRMrTaBxmTQ84FErBKvWXiOwvBAJrPDiEMX231vR29ukofsN2BE6lj52ntP6Cw)

Answer (score 9):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>4</s> 3 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
ƒ-ü
```

Port of [*@ovs*' APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/244212/52210).
-1 byte thanks to [*@nextwayup*'s 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/244218/52210) by using \$ceil(input-random)\$ instead of \$floor(input+random)\$.
Make sure to upvote both of them as well!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///YJN3De/7/N9Iz4TLWs@Qy0DPl0jXVMzLlsuDSNTQw4AJiAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
ƒ    # Random float in the range [0,1]
 -   # Subtract this from the (implicit) input-float
  ü  # Ceil it to an integer
     # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly)
```

Comment: I can't help but read the code as `f***-you` due to the `f-u` visual simplification xD Bonus points for the gag, even if not intended!

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>12</s> <s>11</s> 9 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen*

```
4°LΩ4°/-î
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5NAGn3MrgaS@7uF1//8b6ZkAAA)

Does 05AB1E really not have a function for random(0,1)? Anyway, here's an answer.

Explanation:

```
4°L             # create list of length 10000 (Ždt = 10000)
   Ω            # choose an integer from the list
    4°/        # divide it by 10000 to get a random decimal number
       -       # subtract the random number from the input
        î      # round up
```

Comment: `∞Ždt∍` outputs 1...10000; so it have 1/10000 probability output 7 for input 8. This is **allowed** by the question so you don't need to change anything.

Comment: Yeah i think i should be all right there. I was able to save a byte by using the built-in list creator, which i knew was there somewhere but forgot the command for it :P

Comment: 05AB1E indeed lacks a random float builtin, which is pretty annoying sometimes.. :/ But you can golf the `∞Ždt∍` to simply `4°L` or `тnL`, and the second `Ždt` can be `4°` or `тn` as well.

Comment: ...or `тnDLΩs/-î` or `4°DLΩs/-î`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks, as you can tell i'm still learning but I'm learning new methods every day ;)

Comment: @nextwayup We all have to start somewhere. :) I was getting golfed on almost every 05AB1E answer I posted when I started with it as well. But along the way I learned a lot about the available builtins, and also some useful quirks of certain builtins that are a bit hidden (some of which can be found in the 05AB1E tips page).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen yes, the best way to learn is to make mistakes and learn form them... :). I did see some of the hints on the 05AB1E tips page but i will definitely be going back and taking a longer look at them!

Answer (score 5):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <strike>36</strike> 29 bytes

*-7 thanks to @Sisyphus*

```lua
print((...+math.random())//1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704pzRxwYKlpSVpuhZ7C4oy80o0NPT09LRzE0sy9IoS81LyczU0NfX1DTUhaqBKl0ab6pnGQjkA) Adds a random float between 0 and 1 to the input and then floors.

[image: execute]

[Attempt This Online! (36 byte version)](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704pzRxwYKlpSVpuhY3VQqKMvNKNHITSzL00nLy84s09PT0tMHcosS8lPxcDU1NTYhaqJaV0aYgoGcaCxUAAA)

*insert furious clicking of the execute button*

Comment: I think `print((...+math.random())//1)` works

Comment: ur a pro at lua! surprisingly very people actually use it (apart from you of course)

Comment: @Sisyphus didn't know that `//` existed in Lua. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## x86 machine code (32-bit), <s>18</s> 9 bytes

```
0F C7 F1 39 D1 83 D0 00 C3
```

Saved **9** bytes. Thanks to Peter Cordes.

#### Disassembly

```
0:  0f c7 f1                rdrand ecx
3:  39 d1                   cmp    ecx,edx
5:  83 d0 00                adc    eax,0x0
8:  c3                      ret
```

#### Explanation

The function has the same behavior as `randRound` in the following C code.

```
#include <stdint.h>

static uint32_t rand_u32() {
    uint32_t r;
    __asm__ ("rdrand\t%0" : "=r"(r));
    return r;
}

__attribute__((regparm(3)))
int32_t randRound(uint32_t hi, uint32_t lo) {
    return hi + (rand_u32() < lo);
}
```

`rdrand` reads the hardware random number generator. The Intel manual states the validity of its result should be checked through the carry flag, but according to Peter Cordes, `rdrand` never fails on Ivy Bridge, so this code is always valid on Ivy Bridge, and mostly valid on other machines.

The single statement in `randRound` is all of the algorithm, but I have to explain how the data is represented.

Each fractional number is encoded in 64 bits. The high 32 bits is the integral part and the low 32 bits is the fractional part. The following list shows how each hex value is decoded to an actual value.

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 -> 0
7fff ffff 0000 0000 -> 0x7fff'ffff
8000 0000 0000 0000 -> -0x8000'0000
ffff ffff 0000 0000 -> -1
0000 0001 0000 0001 -> 1 + 1 / 0x1'0000'0000
ffff ffff 0000 0001 -> -1 + 1 / 0x1'0000'0000
ffff ffff ffff ffff -> -1 + 0xffff'ffff / 0x1'0000'0000
```

Such representation is common in fixed point arithmetic because the basic operations are very cheap. Here are some examples using 16/16-bit split, unlike the 32/32-bit split for the entry.

```
typedef uint32_t t_fix;

t_fix fix_add(t_fix x, t_fix y) {
    return x + y;
}

t_fix fix_sub(t_fix x, t_fix y) {
    return x - y;
}

t_fix fix_mul(t_fix x, t_fix y) {
    return (uint64_t)x * y >> 16;
}
```

Comment: Improvement: use `eax` instead of `ax` in the `adc` to not need an operand-size prefix. (The effect on the low half is the same.)

Comment: @m90 I know that saves one byte, but the function makes sense to have a return value in the range `[0, 0xffff]`. Using `eax` would keep an extra `1` in the high bits if `ax` was `0xffff`. I'm not sure if this makes sense (logically?).

Comment: Standard x86 calling conventions allow high garbage in registers above narrow return values.  e.g. an `int16_t` return value is strictly in AX, and callers must not assume anything about the high bits of EAX/RAX.  Also, you don't need to use a `jnc` retry for `rdrand`; golf rules say your code has to work on at least one implementation, and Ivy Bridge (first-gen rdrand) can't exhaust is entropy pool so never fails except maybe on broken HW.  (Even without that, you could probably justify using it blindly, but we don't have to.)  BTW, you don't need `asm goto`, just put a `1:` label inside.

Comment: So you're using 32-bit binary fixed-point with a 16:16 split.  The question talks about "decimal", but then in comments mentions binary floating point, so I guess they don't require actual decimal representation of the fractional part.  This would probably be easier and smaller if you took 64-bit fixed-point (32:32 split), with the integer part in EAX (thus 32-bit mode only; 64-bit wouldn't split it).  Just rdrand / cmp / adc, I think.  Or possibly `rdtsc` if the low 32 bits is random enough on a single run.  (But that would be easier to argue for int16, and still not good for repeated use).

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 44 bytes

```python
lambda i:(i+random())//1
from random import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcg9CoQwEAbQ3lN8ZaIx/oMKe5NtIhIcMJkwpPH0cWGrBy89@eI4Ff/5ltuF43SgXVEjLp4clNZdN1ReOOA/oJBYcl08CwgUMdrZYLKbQW8Xg3ax4491r4AkFLPyirQuLw)

-4 bytes by porting [ovs's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/244212/87681)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
+Ø%X÷¤Ḟ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a number and yields an integer.

Note: given an integer there is a one in \$2^{32}\$ chance of outputting an integer one greater than the input, this is within the \$0.01\%\$ specified.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/78AzViMPbDy15uGPe////dU31jEwB)**

#### How?

```
+Ø%X÷¤Ḟ - Link: number, N
     ¤  - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
 Ø%     -   4294967296
   X    -   random integer from [1..4294967296]
    ÷   -   divide by 4294967296
+       - N add that
      Ḟ - floor
```

Comment: 1 in 256 is a massive `0.39%`; you need to use a much bigger number.

Comment: >.< I remember thinking that and then thinking "Oh 0.01 -- one in a hundred", but of course not! Thanks for spotting that; I've upped it a little.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 18 bytes

```ruby
->n{(n+rand).to_i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWiNPuygxL0VTryQ/PrP2v6GBgV5JZm5qcXVNXk2BApAL5esl55fmlVSnRedpGegZGMba2hrW1v4HAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), <s>32</s> 24 bytes

```
f(a)=(a+random()/2^31)\1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWO9I0EjVtNRK1ixLzUvJzNTT1jeKMDTVjDCHSN10LijLzSjTSNIz0TDQ1uWA8Yz1LJJ6BnikST9dUzwiZb6GpCTEMZicA)

-8, cheers to @alephalpha for the explanation on PARI/GP

Comment: That is because PARI/GP uses the same random seed every time.you start it.

Comment: By the way, the curly brace around `10000` is not necessary. `random({N=2^31})` in the help message means that the argument `N` is optional, and its default value is `2^31`. So you can do `f(a)=(a+random()/2^31)\1`.

Comment: @alephalpha ah makes sense, cheers for the explanation

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, 4 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4764/98541)

```
int(Ans+rand
```

the input is `Ans` (last value entered)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 22 bytes

```perl
$_=int$_+($_/abs)*rand
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jYzr0QlXltDJV4/MalYU6soMS/l/39dUz0j03/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6xYAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal 2.4.1](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/releases/tag/v2.4.1), 4 bytes

```
∆Ṙ+⌊
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%88%86%E1%B9%98%2B%E2%8C%8A&inputs=3.2&header=&footer=)

When rewriting Vyxal, we forgot `∆Ṙ`. It's not a feature, [it's a bug](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/issues/802).

Same as most other answers, adds a random float and floors.

This uses python's `random.random` which is a random 32-bit float in \$[0, 1)\$.

Answer (score 2):

## [Math++](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Math%2B%2B), 23 bytes

```
?>a
_a+!_($rand/(a-_a))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 17 bytes

```julia
!x=ceil(x-rand())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X7HCNjk1M0ejQrcoMS9FQ1Pzf1p@kUKFQmaeQrSpnpGOgqmehY6CrrmeoY6CoQEQG@mZxnIpAAFIXSZInaGVoQFYBAQKijLzSnLyNBQrNMFiqXkpXMjixaW5QDmw5niYZoN4AwMDTX0YA0W9JhfQhP8A)

the same as other answers here

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 88 bytes

```
$
.
\.\d*
$&0000
(\.....).*
$1*_,10000*
L$@`(?<=(-?)(\d+)(_*),_+)((?!\3))?
$1$.($2*_$#4*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYqxCsJAEAX79xfiKrtrsuQuOVBQzs7GT1i4CElhYyH@/3mZZmCY7/p7f16hHvgxV4LBzRcFHYcG2G1DrJWgpQtbVTzpPnO@3rjPwr6chItKV5o573wUyW0nY4paaD9prdEmjHbBYAl9sphw/gM) Link includes test cases. Accurate to `0.01%` as required Explanation:

```
$
.
```

Append a decimal point in case the input is an integer.

```
\.\d*
$&0000
```

Ensure that there are at least 4 digits after the decimal point.

```
(\.....).*
$1*_,10000*
```

Multiply the decimal part of the input by `10,000` and convert it to unary, and separately add another `10,000` in unary.

```
L$@`(?<=(-?)(\d+)(_*),_+)((?!\3))?
```

Randomly match one `_` of the `10,000`, then test whether the random value was less than the decimal fraction.

```
$1$.($2*_$#4*
```

Keep the sign and increment the magnitude if it was.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 39 bytes

```powershell
[Math]::Floor($args[0]+(random -ma 1.))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZExb8IwEIXn@FdYUaiSooSkW0EMVSukDu2AyoQY3MZAJMd2HVsMlN@e@hwDSYsXW3ffu/d0luJAVbOnjLXRdn5s129E7zfT6YIJoeKIqF2zzjfjWBFeihqnNcFFliTtCUXc1HiOH7LHGYqUMLyk5UraynnEM61YxXcxgMmVeREH3qO8kWe0NaR6JZdEV8JSroFT3BcnkyLL74s8v/BQPStsPR2OAUxowj5oo5uOcNrSqubwMBKuIst63M/oiIJIURDcRVsMOVBQbW0iKKb0e5gJWzxwI8fjGQpOmLKG3sRX0sNGdig6IRS@cmk0fjf1J1UYztRZhijsYi8Jx/7YzjWnBZbdXOwW6wEIAlq3B9ztBvqgHa5sZLGnL20IG2KxmzHpWcHKk1HP0P72JZGRf@2ge7HzX/HPzEOx1d@0WpCKWaduB94q7oGpFaYuaRK2vw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 65 bytes

```hs
import System.Random
f x=do n<-randomIO::IO Float;print$floor$n+x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRCG4srgkNVcvKDEvJT@XK02hwjYlXyHPRrcILODpb2Xl6a/glpOfWGJdUJSZV6KSlpOfX6SSp13xPzcxMw@omkshTcEUTOiRSxlCKEsQZQYkNAx0gXKapLP@AwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>53</s></sup> 44 bytes

```c
i;f(float n){i=n+((n>0)-.5)*rand()/(5<<30);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7RqsIwDIbvfYogCIlra9EzONLpi3i8GNsqBe1kLSiOvbq1duNob9L8@fiSip@qKgSjNOpzW3qw1JudzRDtXhIXOS270tZIK8yLYiNJDcFYD5fSWCToZxCfS4g3lwYlkUrZaPON8@5whB30a/HDYCO2DKTIGfBcrGP5HSa87QDfYmPr5h55qaZvAc48mlZjctFq6pZjqyDLEkdJM97ztT@axhsSdFT/8/cuF6fRS5/02sVc43yhge9hUf/ZOQPPwE3MMBvCs9Ln8uQCv70A)

*Saved a whopping 9 bytes thanks to [att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att)!!!*

Comment: Is there some implementation that RAND_MAX is 32767 so you can save some bytes on 1L<<31?

Comment: [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY7RqsIwDIbvfYogCIlra9EzONLpi3i8GNsqBe1kLSiOvbq1duNob9L8@fiSip@qKgSjNOpzW3qw1JudzRDtXhIXOS270tZIK8yLYiNJDcFYD5fSWCToZxCfS4g3lwYlkUrZaPON8@5whB30a/HDYCO2DKTIGfBcrGP5HSa87QDfYmPr5h55qaZvAc48mlZjctFq6pZjqyDLEkdJM97ztT@axhsSdFT/8/cuF6fRS5/02sVc43yhge9hUf/ZOQPPwE3MMBvCs9Ln8uQCv70A)

Comment: @att Oh, very clever - thanks! :D

Comment: @tsh No, RAND_MAX is 2147483647 on all modern computers. Maybe on some obscure embedded systems it'll be a `short int` but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: Finally, a use-case for Turbo C on DOS? :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Yay! But unfortunately we've moved on from using RAND_MAX. :(

Comment: @tsh: Any system with 16-bit `int` will likely have 16-bit RAND_MAX.  For example GCC for MSP430 or AVR (https://godbolt.org/z/v1PcqqaGs), or any old 16-bit x86 compiler.  `rand` returns `int` in ISO C, so it's not going to actually have the type `short int` with a wider `int`.  So I don't think that really helps, `1<<15` on such a system would produce INT_MIN (if the compiler defined the behaviour of a left shift that changed the sign bit; many do but ISO C leaves undefined integer overflow in signed left shifts.  So you'd still need `1L` or `1U`).

Comment: @PeterCordes I mean `32768.` instead of `(1L<<15)`.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com/#/), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

-2 thanks to user ovs' comment:

```
<.@+?@0
```

Original:

```
(<.@+?)&0
```

Port of [@ovs' APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/244212/18872)

Comment: `<.@+?@0` seems to work for 7. btw ov**f** is someone else ;)

Answer (score 1):

## R, 26/31 bytes

For anything that has *probability* in it there **has** to be at least one attempt in R.

Here we have a function in 31 bytes:

```
f=function(x)floor(x+runif(1))
```

and the same thing taking stdin input in 26 bytes:

```
floor(scan(n=1)+runif(1))
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf & Coding Challenges! There was [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/244224/67312), I think. Note that you don't have to include the `f=` since your function isn't recursive (anonymous function submissions are fine). I'd also recommend putting in a Try it Online or Attempt This Online link in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 21 bytes

```
f(n)=ceil(n-random())
```

Press the randomize button at the top left (The icon next to the plus sign) to run the code again.

The simulation code will run the randomization automatically and keep track of the frequency and distribution (more details in the graph).

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yu38g3zxmh)

[Try It On Desmos! - Simulation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vtb6hkcq9m)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
≧Ｘ²φＩ⌊⁺∕‽φφＮ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcqxCoMwEADQvV@R8QJpB3FzKi2FDi3BP7hq1IOYk0uin3/FN79hQRkYo@oHt3vONKee5qWA5yOIM40zk@0uXigVeGAu8IrMAj7WDE/aaQzQYxp5hcme15l32mr51vUXBOypU21urV73@Ac) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≧Ｘ²φ
```

Square the predefined value for `1,000`, so that the error will be less than `0.01%` as desired. (Unfortunately without this the error would be `0.1%`.)

```
Ｉ⌊⁺∕‽φφＮ
```

Divide a random integer between `0` and `1,000,000` by `1,000,000`, add it to the input, and floor the result.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 57 bytes

```py
lambda i:math.floor(i+random.random())
import random,math
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcoxCoAwDEDR3VNkbDEGUQsqeBOXihQDtimhi6eviNOHx89PuSSNNWx7vX08Tg@8Rl8uCreIGm7Vp1Mi/THWNhyzaIEf8HtrEAUGTjDQhCMt2JPDztHgcF6zciomGLa2vg)

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 67 bytes

```swift
import Foundation
let f={(a:Double)in floor(a + .random(in:0..<1))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBCsJADEDR/ZwiywRhqNJV0Z14DRlpA4FpUmJKF6VnH4t/@fjfTTj61mRezANetupYQkxTnQL4sWMZnrZ@6kSiwNXMscAFshcdbUbRocv5fiU6GpvDG87tLx3sCc4WFw1kvOWeKB3tBw)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>45</s> 29 bytes

```javascript
n=>Math.ceil(n-Math.random())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDBTsMwEETv/oo9gGSTxriFSkUhvSFOCIlrFCnGODSVsZHt9pL628MmTStxmtFo94129/Iog/Ldb8yPm6EtB1tu32TccaU7Q20@eS/tl/uhjA1EORsiRN9JE6CEpRCiIKQiACv@uEB54E@jCL4eJV/z1WQ2pOat8y9S7aiFcgs9hmeYcgcbkdWnAjMcAmp0hA4jUaA8z3Xos4xNi5dVjzMttayYMwRVvsaQXv3pBIJBBstxJs2lzmhu3DdtPnQ4mBim1pvepmZCvX/utYpcWyzW4cxiPDgfKbteQSu/AFWz8Zh/TMjh1UXE@QSdRVVwf/nY3fixdAuunZOGYWNiwx8)

I am an idiot, this is a much better way of doing it.

Here is my old solution:

```javascript
n=>Math.random()>(n>0?n:-n)%1?~~n:n>0?-~n:~-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBBb4MwDIXv/AofVikZJQvtKnVl0NO00zRp1woJlsFKxZwppL1Q@OvMobTSTs95sr/n@JCf8kaZ6tcGp/VQxgPGyVtu98Lk@KV/GE8YJnKLmwD5LNz2PW7cOyDtAxw8pbGxYE2V1w3EEEopI8/beQAL8TgnWYonJ1KsnAQrsRiLtZeKUpuXXO0ZQpxAS@YFpvQRLbHaLiKPmoDVhYWKLBmRPE9xVPs@Hwevo4Z6SoY8mjwC7UxKJrvV5zNIDj6ErqebQnVdiFp/s@yjaI61bcbUuxa7bES9fx4KZUWBFFw0Fxa/rc92Zg4q5e4X/2AQwKu2xDEdVEiq4OF6qnt3qm4GupycjFNUx4c/)

A bit convoluted to make it work for negatives, but essentially it checks whether the result from `Math.random()` is greater than the absolute value of the input. If it is, return the input rounded towards zero, otherwise away from zero.